# Are UML diagram reviews on-topic for CodeReview?

Tags: discussion

I would like to post a UML diagram for review on StackExchange.  The response to the [question I asked on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134334/161340) seems to point to CodeReview being the place to ask, but the answer was also by no means definitive.

Would it be on-topic to request a UML diagram review here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I wonder how you might go about posting the UML diagram? Since it is recommended to provide the artifact to be reviewed inline with the question.
- Another issue I see is that a review of UML essentially is a design review rather than a code review. I wonder if it is within the purview of this site.
- This is also related to the question of other formats perhaps - like latex, HTML-sites, etc.

A possible way to solve it may be to just ask the question, and let the community express its interest.

Comment: 1. Use yUML 2. So pm.stackexchange? 3. Use yUML

Comment: Downvote because question isn't actually answered.